# How to bundle TinyMCE vue integration?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, tinymce, vue-component, laravel-6

I want to use tinymce vue in my laravel vue SPA app (Laravel 6 and vue@2.6.10)

I want to bundle in the app.js and app.css all the content. After I installed :

```
npm install tinymce
npm install @tinymce/tinymce-vue
```

I have imported globally app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';
import 'tinymce/tinymce.min';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min'

Vue.component('tinymce-editor', Editor);

...
```

and in app.scss:

```
@import '~tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css';
@import '~tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css';
@import '~tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css';
```

It compiles fine...but when I load the component that contains the editor

```
<tinymce-editor></tinymce-editor>
```

it complains in the browser console (404) that it cannot find the css files that I have imported in the app.scss

What am I missing ???

Comment: I think you have a typo you've missed `.js` in `tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min`

Comment: @Philippe ... no. It doesn`t matter if I put .js or not :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell tinymce that it doesn't need to worry about those files.

```
<tinymce-editor
  :init="{content_css: false, skin: false}"
>
</tinymce-editor>
```